# Computer on home network resolves host name to different IP addresses

Tags: tomato, dnsmasq

I have a computer on my home network that is also accessible from the internet through a dyndns host name.
When I am at home, I need the xxx.dyndns.org host name for my machine to resolve to an IP on my local network (10.0.1.X), and when I am away from home, it is resolved to the IP that is confogured on DYNDNS.

I set up a host record on my TomatoUSB router, which looks like this:
host-record=XXX,XXX.dyndns.org,10.0.1.5

When I am at home, and I ping the machine, it correctly resolves to 10.0.1.5 - for a minute or two, then it starts resolving to the internet IP address (dyndns) - which of course doesnt work anymore because its the WAN address of my modem.

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Is the computer setup to use the home router as it's DNS server?

Comment: Yes - it gets the router IP through DHCP. The initial DNS queries are mapped correctly by the dnsmasq... its only after a minute or so that it reverts to the internet IP...

Answer (score 0):

Run `nslookup xxx.dyndns.org 10.0.1.1`, assuming that this is your router IP address. If it keeps responding correctly, the problem may be related to your computer DNS configuration.